# Get dependencies Ids Algorithm

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have this problem and I came out with a solution but what is the best way to solve this problem ? Thank you in advance.

Given an array of strings and an array of tasks you need to return a sorted array with tasks and dependencies tasks ids.

Example:

```
$inputs = ['A'];

$tasks = [
    ['id' => 1, 'type' => 'A', 'dependencies' => ['B']],
    ['id' => 2, 'type' => 'A', 'dependencies' => ['C']],
    ['id' => 3, 'type' => 'B', 'dependencies' => ['C']],
    ['id' => 4, 'type' => 'C', 'dependencies' => ['A', 'F']],
    ['id' => 5, 'type' => 'D', 'dependencies' => []],
    ['id' => 6, 'type' => 'D', 'dependencies' => ['F']],
    ['id' => 7, 'type' => 'E', 'dependencies' => ['D']],
    ['id' => 8, 'type' => 'F', 'dependencies' => []]
];
```

Expected output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8]

// Comments.
Id 1 of tasks['type'] = A  - [1]
Id 2 of tasks['type'] = A  - [1, 2]

Tasks id 1 has dependencies B then 
Id 3 of tasks['type'] = B  - [1, 2, 3]

Tasks id 3 has dependencies C then 
Id 4 of tasks['type'] = C  - [1, 2, 3, 4]

Tasks id 4 has dependencies A and F. Take F then 
Id 8 of tasks['type'] = F  - [1, 2, 3, 4, 8]
```

So far this is the solution I built, but I would like to know if I am in the right path.

```
print_r(getId($inputs, $tasks));

function getId($inputs, $tasks){
    $id   = [];
    $deps = [];
    $values = [];
    $result = [];

    foreach($inputs as $input){
        foreach($tasks as $task){
            if ($task['type'] == $input){
                $result[$task['id']] = $task['id'];

                foreach($task['dependencies'] as $dependencies){
                    if($dependencies != $input){
                        $deps[] = $dependencies;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $values[$task['type']]['id'][] = $task['id'];
                $values[$task['type']]['deps'] = $task['dependencies'];
            }
        }

        foreach($deps as $d){
            if(count($values[$d]['deps']) > 0)
            {
                foreach($values[$d]['deps'] as $nDeps)
                {
                    if($nDeps != $input){
                        $result[] = $values[$nDeps]['id'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach( $result as $res){
        if (is_array($res)){
            foreach( $res as $r){
                $id[] = $r;
            }
        }
        else {
            $id[] = $res;
        }
    }

    return array_unique($id);
}
```

Comment: Your current solution doesn't print `3`. Besides, the code is pretty verbose. There is scope to make it more concise.

Comment: At a glance, this is just a simple graph traversal.

Comment: Thank you for the comments nice_dev, I thought the same thing when finished but I don't know how to implemented.

Comment: Could you test this? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/88f828af134042d3e080423b57def5af4cbbab34

Comment: Great nice_dev, it works, let me study your code now

Comment: what do you think is the runtime and space complexity ?

Comment: What you want is called a topological sort.  Google gave me https://github.com/marcj/topsort.php as an implementation in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Full Snippet:**

```
<?php

function getId($inputs, $tasks){
   $types = [];
   $dependencies = [];
   foreach($tasks as $task){
       $types[$task['type']] =  $types[$task['type']] ?? [];
       $dependencies[$task['type']] = $dependencies[$task['type']] ?? [];
       $types[$task['type']][] = $task['id'];
       $dependencies[$task['type']] = array_unique(array_merge($dependencies[$task['type']],$task['dependencies']));
   }
   
   $res = [];
   $vis = [];
   foreach($inputs as $in){
       $queue = [];
       foreach($types[$in] as $id){
           if(!isset($vis[$id])){
               $vis[$id] = true;
               $queue[] = [$id , $in];
           }
       }
       while(count($queue) > 0){
           $d = array_shift($queue);
           $res[] = $d[0];
           $vis[$d[0]] = true;
           $type = $d[1];
           foreach($dependencies[$type] as $de_type){
               foreach($types[$de_type] as $id){
                   if(!isset($vis[$id])){
                       $vis[$id] = true;
                       $queue[] = [$id , $de_type];
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   
   sort($res);
   return $res;
}
```

---

**Step 1 : Dependency and type maps:**

```
foreach($tasks as $task){
       $types[$task['type']] =  $types[$task['type']] ?? [];
       $dependencies[$task['type']] = $dependencies[$task['type']] ?? [];
       $types[$task['type']][] = $task['id'];
       $dependencies[$task['type']] = array_unique(array_merge($dependencies[$task['type']],$task['dependencies']));
}
```

- Collect all types of tasks according to their type. This will be helpful in accumulating all tasks of a particular type.
- Create a dependency map(associative array) as well by collecting all dependencies for a particular type. This involves merging of all tasks' dependencies which have the same type.

---

**Step 2: Add those tasks whose types are requested in $inputs**

```
$queue = [];
foreach($types[$in] as $id){
   if(!isset($vis[$id])){
       $vis[$id] = true;
       $queue[] = [$id , $in];
   }
}
```

The above snippet is to just add nodes/tasks in the queue(only those who haven't been added before)

---

**Step 3: Loop over all dependencies**

```
while(count($queue) > 0){
     $d = array_shift($queue);
     $res[] = $d[0];
     $vis[$d[0]] = true;
     $type = $d[1];
     foreach($dependencies[$type] as $de_type){
         foreach($types[$de_type] as $id){
             if(!isset($vis[$id])){
                 $vis[$id] = true;
                 $queue[] = [$id , $de_type];
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Above snippet loops over each tasks one by one popping them out from the queue.
Once a task is popped out, we loop over all it's type dependencies. The inner loop
loops over those tasks which have the current type in iteration. This way, the whole
dependency graph is visited and appended.