# PHP topological sort

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

### LIST: controller name => priority:required controllers

```
$array(
"controller_3" => "3",
"controller_1" => "1:controller_2",
"controller_2" => "2",
"controller_4" => "1:controller_2&controller_1",
"controller_x" => "2:controller_not_exists",
"controller_loopexit1" => "4:controller_loopexit2",
"controller_loopexit2" => "5:controller_loopexit1"
)
```

sorted and expected output:

```
controller_2
controller_1
controller_4
controller_3
```

---

First sort by priority,
then reorder based on required controllers to be loaded before.
ensure not to be stuck in an infinite loop due to controllers requiring each other.

---

I assume I'll need something like this:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($controllers_array, 'cmp');
```

Please help solve this with these steps:

1. Remove infinite loop controllers (ex: controller_loopexit1 & controller_loopexit2)
2. Remove controllers that have a dependency of a controller that doesn`t exist (ex: controller_x depending on controller_not_exists.)
3. Sort remaining items by priority number, lowest comes first
4. Second sort by dependencies

Comment: Your input contains 7 items, your output only 4? How is "priority" defined?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, if the required controllers aren't met, then the item is removed

Comment: What you need is a topological sort. I answered a similar question here for dependencies which should get you started. Only additional thing you would have to add at the end is sort by priority. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67219177/get-dependencies-ids-algorithm/

Comment: [`This`](https://github.com/marcj/topsort.php) should also help.

Comment: @knittl: priority is lower number first, then second sort step is to sort is based on required controllers

Comment: You have 2 independent problems here: 1) Removing the cycles 2) Sorting. You shouldn't mix 2 problems in the same question.

Comment: it's okay @Olivier as far as both problems are related to the same questions. We should tell him only that please describe your question in proper manner and write your problems as an independent list in the same question. It's okay to raise two problems in the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Code:

```
<?php

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

class TheSortedControllers{

    private $inputControllerList = [];
    private $inputControllerMap = [];
    private $sorter = null;

    function __construct($inputControllerList){
        $this->inputControllerList = $inputControllerList;
        $this->sorter = new \MJS\TopSort\Implementations\StringSort();
    }

    function inputMapper(){

        $controllersList = $this->inputControllerList;

        foreach($controllersList as $controllerId=>$controllerData){

            $controllerData = (explode(":",$controllerData));
            $this->inputControllerMap[$controllerId]['priority'] = (int)$controllerData[0];

            if(isset($controllerData[1])){
                $this->inputControllerMap[$controllerId]['required'] = explode("&",$controllerData[1]);
            }

        }

    }

    function sortByPriority($a, $b)
    {
        return $a['priority'] - $b['priority'];
    }

    function sort(){

        $this->inputMapper();

        uasort($this->inputControllerMap, array($this, "sortByPriority"));

        foreach($this->inputControllerMap as $controllerID=>$controllerData){

            $required = $controllerData['required'] ?? [];

            $this->sorter->add($controllerID, $required);
        }

        return $this->sorter->sort();
    }
}


$controllersList =  array(
    "controller_3" => "3",
    "controller_1" => "1:controller_2",
    "controller_2" => "2",
    "controller_4" => "1:controller_2&controller_1",
);

$theSortedControllers = new TheSortedControllers($controllersList);

try {
    $outputControllersList = $theSortedControllers->sort();
    print_r($outputControllersList);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

## Usage:

1. I am using https://github.com/marcj/topsort.php. To use it you
   must have Composer. Run `composer require marcj/topsort` to install
   the code dependency.
2. That's it. In case of an exception, the code does not automatically remove the nodes (controllers), it's best to use human intervention to make sure you resolve those exceptions and have a proper input.

## Examples:

### Case 1

Input (Your Original Input - Missing Dependency):

```
$controllersList =  array(
    "controller_3" => "3",
    "controller_1" => "1:controller_2",
    "controller_2" => "2",
    "controller_4" => "1:controller_2&controller_1",
    "controller_x" => "2:controller_not_exists",
    "controller_loopexit1" => "4:controller_loopexit2",
    "controller_loopexit2" => "5:controller_loopexit1"
);
```

Output:

```
Message: Dependency `controller_not_exists` not found, required by `controller_x`
```

---

### Case 2

Input (Add the missing dependency, you still have circular-dependency/infinite-loop):

```
$controllersList =  array(
    "controller_3" => "3",
    "controller_1" => "1:controller_2",
    "controller_2" => "2",
    "controller_4" => "1:controller_2&controller_1",
    "controller_x" => "2:controller_not_exists",
    "controller_loopexit1" => "4:controller_loopexit2",
    "controller_loopexit2" => "5:controller_loopexit1",
    "controller_not_exists" => "10:controller_2",
);
```

Output:

```
Message: Circular dependency found: controller_loopexit1->controller_loopexit2->controller_loopexit1
```

---

### Case 3

Input (Removed the controllers with circular dependency):

```
$controllersList =  array(
    "controller_3" => "3",
    "controller_1" => "1:controller_2",
    "controller_2" => "2",
    "controller_4" => "1:controller_2&controller_1",
    "controller_x" => "2:controller_not_exists",
    "controller_not_exists" => "10:controller_2",
);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => controller_2
    [1] => controller_1
    [2] => controller_4
    [3] => controller_not_exists
    [4] => controller_x
    [5] => controller_3
)
```

---

### Case 4

Input (Removed `controller_not_exists` and `controller_x`):

```
$controllersList =  array(
    "controller_3" => "3",
    "controller_1" => "1:controller_2",
    "controller_2" => "2",
    "controller_4" => "1:controller_2&controller_1",
);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => controller_2
    [1] => controller_1
    [2] => controller_4
    [3] => controller_3
)
```